# cant display collection data from flutter firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, builder

I am trying to obtain the data of my documents in a `ListView` from doc. It tends to receive the data I see an error at `doc['title']` stating :

> The operator `[]` isn't defined for the type `Object? Function()`

Also when I print it I see this :

> Closure: () => Map<String, dynamic> from Function 'data':.

```dart
StreamBuilder(
    stream: ref.snapshots(),
    builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text('Something went wrong');
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        return ListView.builder(itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context,index) {
            var doc = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data;
            print(doc);
            return ListTile(
                title: Text('title'),
            );
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: Can you please post the error log? What documentation are you using to come up with the code? I see that you are retrieving the data using:

`snapshot.data!.docs[index].data`.

But according to this [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html), you need to use `data()`

Comment: data() seemed to be the problem

Comment: @ibrahim If you resolved your issue it is a [good practice in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to post your solution as an answer.